# Google Search Console Add Domain and/or Site URL?

Tags: google-search-console

If I have added a property as https://example.com, and then decide I would rather add the whole domain using TXT, should I then remove the url-based property please?

Answer (score 0):

**It's not really needed !**

Personnaly I kept both of them !

Like that, you can see more details datas : In the url-based you see only the subdomain concerned; and with the domain using TXT you see the all domain.

Sometime could be usefull to have also an or some subdomnains + the global..